# in R / RStudio running on Windows, can we make message(), warning() and error() use different colors in the console?

Tags: r, logging, colors, rstudio

I use a lot of messages e.g. `message("dadida")` in one of my projets, and it is becomming annoying to see all this red text everywhere, always making me wonder if there's an error or a warning hidden somewhere.

I need those messages in the end product so I can't just remove them. But if there was a way to make messages, warnings and errors appear in different colors in the console, that would solve my problem. I haven't found a way to do this.

**Edit**

Thanks all for your input. I hadn't realized that the red color for all those types of messages was specific to RStudio. In the RGui, all is just plain white text. If customizing the colors is not feasible in RGui, maybe it is in RStudio?

Comment: If you are on linux, this package appears to change the colors...
http://www.lepem.ufc.br/jaa/colorout.html

Comment: Oh it's so unfortunate, I need to work on Windows for this project. This is _exactly_ what I'd need!

Comment: If you type message, warning, and stop at the console prompt, you can see the functions that are executed when a message/warning/error occur.  I suspect these functions can be modified to change the text attributes such as color/font.

Comment: Here's an old post that suggest where to change the source code to enable different color for console output.  https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2010-February/007146.html

Comment: On wndows, you can install cygwin, then go to the math section, and install R statistics package.  Then the previous linux solution may work on windows...

Comment: I was not able to find a solution to this problem, but [I have asked RStudio on Twitter](https://twitter.com/KirkegaardEmil/status/681829399533109249). Let's hope they answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make error and warning messages print in a specific color in RStudio, you have to edit your editor theme.

1. Find the **Editor theme** that you're using by going to the Appearance Preferences Pane in Global Options.

[image: Custom Editor Themes from https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011846747-Using-RStudio-Themes#custom-editor-themes]

2. Search your machine for that editor theme (you'll probably have to replace spaces with underscores in your search).  You're looking for a file with the extension `.rstheme`.
3. Copy that file to a new location you can easily find again and rename it something like `my_theme.rstheme`.
4. Open `my_theme.rstheme` with a text editor
5. At the top of the file, you should see something like `/* rs-theme-name: Example name */`.  Replace that with a new title for your theme: `/* rs-theme-name: My theme */`.
6. At the bottom of the file, add this line: `.GD15MCFCOTB{color: #FF0000;}` replacing `#FF0000` with whatever hex color code you want to use.

(I have no idea why, but the CSS class `GD15MCFCOTB` is what RStudio uses to designate warning and error messages.  I discovered this by right clicking on an error message in RStudio and using the HTML inspector.)

7. Save and close your updated `.rstheme` file.
8. Go back to RStudio, navigate to the Appearance Preferences Pane in Global Options, and click the button `Add...`
9. Select the `.rstheme` file you created earlier and click `Open`.
10. You should now see your theme in the list of **Editor themes**. Select it and click OK.  That will apply your new theme.

See this page for more info on custom themes in RStudio: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011846747-Using-RStudio-Themes#custom-editor-themes

Comment: Thanks, I had totally forgotten I had asked that question! (Not even sure theme files existed at the time)

Answer (score 3):

While I am not aware of a way of customizing the output in RGui or RStudio for Windows, using cat() instead of message() will avoid the red text in RStudio. Instead of using

```
message("Hello!")
```

use

```
cat("Hello!\n")
```

(note the \n that is needed to get a new line).

There are some subtle differences between message() and cat(), which may be relevant when you are redirecting your output e.g. to a LaTeX document using Sweave, so cat() may not be a suitable substitute in all settings.